# server core and command prompt

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-command-prompt, windows-server-core

Thought came to mind as I am studying for my 40-711 MCSA test later today, and I'm not near my server lab at home to test.

Do CMD commands work in a server core install of MS Server 2012 R2?  For example, I'm refreshing up on DNS and the thought came to mind if I wanted to get the currently cached DNS records, could I use ipconfig /displaydns instead of Show-DNSServerCache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the commands you would normally use (ipconfig, netsh etc) will work in Server Core.

Edited to add: Here's some additional commands you may find helpful -https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630943.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I actually passed my test yesterday, and I don't recall having any server vote command related questions.

Comment: Congrats on passing!!